# linux server not rebooting after reinstalling grub

Tags: linux, grub

I have a hetzner linux server. It was provided without any raid configuration and debian 10. So using their installimage script I reinstalled the OS with Debian version 9 and the raid was configured. But after the disks in the raid was synced, I am unable to reboot the machine. So I booted the machine into rescue mode and reinstalled the grub using the following 2 methods

```
Method1: mount /dev/md2 /mnt
mount /dev/md1 /mnt/boot
mount -t dev -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -t proc -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sys -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc
dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc


2nd Method:

# update-grub && grub-install /dev/sda
# update-grub && grub-install /dev/sdb
```

After the grub is reinstall, when `chroot /mnt` is done, the `/mnt/boot` folder has `vmlinuz-4.9.0-11-amd64` and `initrd.img-4.9.0-11-amd64`. But when exited from chroot, when checking in the root /boot folder there is only `initrd.img-4.9.0-11-amd64`. Is this causing the issue with the boot. As per my understanding the contents in /mnt/boot folder are correct and the boot should be happening without any issues. Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: You might have some more luck getting a response at https://serverfault.com/ (they specialise in server queries)

Comment: Check [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/software-raid1-grub-boot-debian-etch-p2), especially the part concerning the fstab and grub configuration